# Anyone able to help identify what aerofoil this is?

Tags: wing, airfoil

Firstly, apologies for the potato quality of the image below. I am attempting to determine the qualities of a VTOL and cannot find any data online. If anyone knows what aerofoil this could be that would help a bunch! (the green line is the upper edge and the yellow line is the lower edge)

[image]

Comment: Do you have any other info regarding where this is from? Is it properly scaled? It looks quite thick, as if it was distorted, or a special root-section foil.

Comment: The video I got this from is this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LeFxjRMv5U8 @ 0:14 (I used the step timer to capture this screenshot when the wing was bent to be in line with the camera)

This is the only image I can find of this craft of the aerofoil section. The chord is 880mm (measured from another drawing). Really just need to find the lift and drag polars so therefore need the aerofoil.

Comment: It is not even listed in the airfoiltools database. The closest is the [Wortmann FX 08-S-176](http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=fx08s176-il), but the Cora airfoil has its maximum thickness much more forward which should give it less laminar flow but gentle stall characteristics.

Answer (score 2):

Try contacting the local FAA Flight Standards District Office (FSDO-'fizzdoe') for help. They may be able to tell you how to get a copy of the aircraft's certification documents which may indicate the airfoil used. Mention the aircraft's N-number: N301XZ. To locate the nearest Flight Standards District Office, see here:

https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/field_offices/fsdo/

Comment: … or you look it up here: https://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/NNum_Results.aspx?NNumbertxt=301XZ. It seems to be an electric rotorcraft, manufactured by [ZEE Aero](https://electrek.co/guides/zee-aero/) and called Mule SPA. That does not help much.